# Gradle use correct version of dependency

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Currently, my project needs Cassandra as the database, so, I used org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:2.1.9.RELEASE as the solution, and I also used spring-security-core 5.1.5 as the solution, but within spring-security-core 5.1.5, seems it has org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:2.1.6.RELEASE dependency.

So I am wondering how to fix this in gradle within IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use cassandra:2.1.6 everywhere to avoid version conflicts. I don't think you have to rewrote any parts of your code.

Or you could try to remove 2.1.6 version with 
compile.exclude group: 'com.example.x', module: 'x'

But it could cause spring-security to work unstable. So first solution preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest excluding org.springframework.data:spring-data-cassandra:2.1.6.RELEASE in spring-security-core 5.1.5

Refer this link how to exclude  - https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleDependency.html#exclude-java.util.Map-